# My data fetching too slow. Is there anything wrong with my sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm current facing a issue in my project. When i search a product, it take too much time to fetch data.
This is sql code.

```
SELECT * FROM product_info 
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT bulk_stock_info.bulk_unit_buy_price,bulk_stock_info.general_unit_sale_price,bulk_stock_info.bulk_unit_sale_price,bulk_stock_info.product_id as pid 
        FROM bulk_stock_info 
        ORDER BY bulk_id DESC
        ) bulk_stock_info 
    ON bulk_stock_info.pid = product_info.product_id 
WHERE (`product_name` RLIKE ' +$query') OR `product_name` LIKE '$query%';"
```

Comment: Remove `ORDER BY bulk_id DESC` from the subquery.

Comment: Why `ORDER BY`?

Comment: what's the point of ordering a subquery? The rows from that just get joined to the the rows in the main query based on the `ON` clause, so the order you queried them in isn't important.

Comment: Without knowing the result of  an explain on your Quere we cannot help much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to use a subquery or outer join:

```
SELECT pi.*
       bsi.bulk_unit_buy_price, bsi.general_unit_sale_price, bsi.bulk_unit_sale_price
FROM product_info pi JOIN
     bulk_stock_info bsi
     ON bsi.product_id = pi.product_id 
WHERE pi.product_name RLIKE ' +$query' OR pi.product_name LIKE '$query%'
```